# Gitignore - Allow only one folder and in that folder, dont allow those files without name ending with `.json`

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to do this: allow only one folder and in that folder, don't allow those files without name ending with `.json`

Is this possible ?

Example:

```
a/one.txt
a/one.config.yaml
a/two.json
b/one.text
b/one.config.yaml
b/three.json
```

In this, only 2 should be allowed

```
a/one.txt
a/one.config.yaml
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend against the "everything except" pattern when you can. It especially gets tricky with sub-directories.

This should work for you though, in a `.gitignore`:

```
# ignore all folders
*/

# except this folder
!*a/

# business as usual for files
# ignore the extensions you don't want
*.json
```

Comment: The question text only mentions the .config.yaml, but the example shows more being accepted. This answer is intended to align with the example given.